# need help integrating mySQL into my Node.js project (that uses React)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, npm

so i'm making a web-app using Node.js, and it has to get info from my local database in mySQL workbench. i decided to create the frontend interface first and then implement the functionality. all of these are new to me.

when i type in 'npm start,' the web browser pops up at localhost:3000 and the frontend is great. but all the tutorials i'm finding for connecting mySQL to Node.js tell me to do 'node Main.js' or something like that, and it's just got nothing to do with the website.

i can't figure out how to proceed. if helpful, here are how my files are organized:

[File structure of my app in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0eJJ.png)

Any help is MUCH APPRECIATED!!

Answer (score 0):

When it's referring to "node main.js", node is the keyword is to start a node application. main.js is the file that has your server start up information.

Did you create these files yourself or are you using a tutorials files?

You need to set up a server to connect your database. I'd look at [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/) for your server then to connect to your mysql database, use [mysql2 npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2).

Comment: thank you! 
i was able to connect to the database in a file i made called server.js.

Answer (score 0):

Base to your file structure, i see a file named server.js, it must be the server start up file. So in your case try `node server.js`
A better way is configuring your package.js to run them both at once, something like:

> "scripts": {
>
> ```
> "start": "react-scripts start && node server.js",
> ....
> ```